# XAML x:Bind Selected Value won't bind to nullable int

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

There is some strange behavior with XAML x:Bind and attempting to bind to a nullable int:

Binding defintions:

```
public ObservableCollection<ListObject> List { get; set; }

public class ListObject
   {
      public int? ID { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

XAML

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.List}"
           DisplayMemberPath="Name"
           SelectedValuePath="ID"
           SelectedValue="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The following works without issue:

```
private int _selectedID;

public int SelectedID
   {
      get { return _selectedID; }
      set { _selectedID = value; }
   }
```

This does not work and is giving me an invalid object to int? casting exception:

```
private int? _selectedID;
    
public int? SelectedID
   {
      get { return _selectedID; }
      set { _selectedID = value; }
   }
```

Why does the XAML binding work on a regular int whereas the nullable int causes issues?

**UPDATED**

After looking into this issue a bit more it appears the g.cs file is correctly casting the int, however the cast is not generated automatically if the binding target is a nullable struct.

g.cs file for the int binding target:

```
private void UpdateTwoWay_25_SelectedItem()
            {
                if (this.initialized)
                {
                    if (this.dataRoot != null)
                    {
                        if (this.dataRoot.ViewModel != null)
                        {
                            this.dataRoot.ViewModel.SelectedID = (global::System.Int32)this.obj25.SelectedItem;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is what the g.cs file looks like on the nullable struct:

```
private void UpdateTwoWay_25_SelectedItem()
            {
                if (this.initialized)
                {
                    if (this.dataRoot != null)
                    {
                        if (this.dataRoot.ViewModel != null)
                        {
                           // This line is the issue
                            this.dataRoot.ViewModel.SelectedID = this.obj25.SelectedItem;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Manually updating the g.cs file has the binding working correctly. I don't know if this is an issue with the new x:bind, with WinUI 3 or the Windows App SDK.

Either way, I created a bug in the Microsoft-UI-XAML git:
[Issue 6558](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6558)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x:Bind` doesn't currently handle `null` values correctly. As stated in [this GitHub issue from 2020](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2166), they "will look at fixing this *post* WinUI 3.0".

Comment: Thank you for adding the related issue. My fix for now is to just bind to the object itself and select the property from there. Adds another null check but it'll do.